# Google spreadsheet room reservation

Tags: excel, filter, google-sheets

This is actually my solution to a simple question that is, apparantly, difficult to find an answer for: How do I reserve a room without double booking it?

My solution was this...

The spreadsheet:
[image]

Cell C3 contains a validated drop down list of rows F3:F20 (so you can add more)

The formula for Cell F3:

```
=FILTER(E3:E20, E3:E20<>C3, E3:E20<>C3, E3:E20<>C4, E3:E20<>C5, E3:E20<>C6,E3:E20<>C7, E3:E20<>C8, E3:E20<>C9, E3:E20<>C10, E3:E20<>C11 )
```

Let me know what you think!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's ok!

This formula is easier to use:

```
=FILTER(E3:E,countif(E3:E,C3:C)=0)
```